# How do prevent race condition when deleting a GWAN KV stored struct?

Tags: c, locking, race-condition, data-storage, g-wan

After several months of evaluating and reevaluating and planing different data structures and web/application servers I'm now at a point where I need to bang my head around with implementation details. The (at the moment theoretical) question I'm facing is this:

Say I'm using GWANs KV store to store C structs for Users and the like (works fine, tested), how should I go about removing these objects from KV, and later on from memory, without encountering a race condition?

This is what I'm at at the moment:

Thread A:

- grab other objects referencing the one to be deleted
- set references to NULL
- delete object

Thread B:

- try to get object -> kv could return object, as it's not yet deleted
- try to do something with the object -> could already be deleted here, so I would access already freed memory?

or something else which could happen:

Thread B:

- get thing referencing object
- follow reference -> object might not be deleted here
- do something with reference -> object might be deleted here -> problem

or

Thread B:

- got some other object which could reference the to be deleted object
- grab object which isn't yet deleted
- set reference to object -> object might be deleted here -> problem

Is there a way to avoid those kind of conditions, except for using locks? I've found a latitude of documents describing algorithms dealing with different producer/consumer situations, hashtables, ... with even sometimes wait free implementations (I haven't yet found a good example to show me the difference between lock-free and wait-free, though I get it conceptually), but I haven't been able to figure out how to deal with these kind of things.

Am I overthinking this, or is there maybe an easy way to avoid all these situations? I'm free to change the data- and -storage layout in any way I want, and I can use processor specific instructions freely (e.g. CAS)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several questions there:

> deleting a GWAN KV stored struct

When removing a KV from a persistence pointer or freeing the KV, you have to make sure that nobody is dereferencing freed data.

This is application dependent. You can introduce some tolerance by using G-WAN memory pools which will make data survive a KV deletion as long as the memory is not overwrited (or the pool freed).

> deleting a GWAN KV key-value pair

G-WAN's KV store does the bookkeeping (using atomic intrinsics) to protect values fetched by threads and unprotects them after the request has been processed.

If you need to keep data for a longer time, make a copy.

Other storage tools, like in-memory SQLite use locks. In this case, lock granularity is very important.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand it right, it would be possible to use a G-WAN memory pool for a KV key-value pair (there any examples to look at regarding that combination?) so it would automatically be freed when all accessing requests end, and all I'd have to do is the KV delete, and if any other thread would access the struct at after that, it would be fine, as the memory pool would only be freed after all accessing threads finished?

Comment: Edit: deleted, as what I wrote didn't even make sense by itself ;)

Comment: After banging my head around this more I figured out that what you wrote actually perfectly answers part of my question and the rest is just something I have to solve algorithmically (making sure freed stuff is not referenced anymore). Thanks!